# How to reduce form code duplication in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a form in CakePHP with a few dozen fields in it. From all the examples I have seen, there is duplicate form code for an add view and an edit view.

Is there any tricks to keep the duplication out? What is best method in CakePHP for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I do, is to put all form fields in an element, and then insert the element in the add.ctp and edit.ctp

Don't forget to add the hidden field with the id in the edit.ctp

This way all visible elements are in one file, easier to maintain.

```
View/MyModel/add.ctp
echo $this->Form->create('MyModel');
echo $this->element('my_form'); 
echo $this->Form->end();

View/MyModel/edit.ctp
echo $this->Form->create('MyModel');
echo $this->Form->input('id');
echo $this->element('my_form'); 
echo $this->Form->end();

View/Elements/my_form.ctp
// your form inputs
// whatever they are
```

Comment: this worked exactly! The form helper + elements makes this ridiculously easy!

Comment: This solution is so obvious that it's brilliant. Meaning I should have thought of this, but didn't! I take the caveats of other commenters here to heart - combining these forms completely can lead to a mess of if statements that I want to avoid, but this gets the best of both. Two completely separate forms that overlap more than not is too much duplication for my liking, so this is a neat trick to remove most of that and make maintenance easier going forward (update one form, not two).

Answer (score 7):

You should **NOT** merge those views, because **add/edit are different actions** and deserve separate view files. As your application grows you will realize that its good to have separate views to reduce complexity of `if else conditions`.

If you still want to avoid the separate files, Use

```
function add() {
    .....
    $this->render('edit')
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've done this before, but reverted back to having separate views, mainly for my own sanity.

It's easy enough to do. The edit requires an input for the record id. This is usually hidden. Any default form values for the add form will have to be contained in conditionals so that the stored values are not overwritten with defaults when you are editing a record

On the controller side of things, you'll need a conditional statement to decide whether to act as an add or edit depending on whether the `$this->data['MyModel']['id']` is set.

I think that covers it - if I think of anything else I'll add it in.

My work pattern tends to be to build the edit view, then copy and paste to create the basis for the add view.

Comment: you can have a id in an add form

Comment: @dogmatic - yes, but not usually. In that case you'd have to filter a different way. I'm not suggesting a generic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

this code will check if you have admin_form.ctp or form.ctp which will make it use the same code for add / edit

https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/dev/app_controller.php#L389

1.3 submits the forms automatically to where the are from so when you go to /edit/1 it will post to there, and /add will post to add.

that is all you need to do. if you have a edit that is vastly different to the add, then you just create the 2 files. when you want them the same, just make the one.

Answer (score 0):

in your app controller

```
public function render($view = null, $layout = null) {

    $viewPaths = App::path('View', $this->plugin);
    $rootPath = $viewPaths[0] . DS . $this->viewPath . DS;
    $requested = $rootPath . $view . '.ctp';
    if (in_array($this->request->action, array('admin_edit', 'admin_add', 'edit', 'add'))) {
        $viewPath = $rootPath . $this->request->action . '.ctp';
        if (!file_exists($requested) && !file_exists($viewPath)) {
            if (strpos($this->request->action, 'admin_') === false) {
                $view = 'form';
            } else {
                $view = 'admin_form';
            }
        }
    }
    return parent::render($view, $layout);
}
```

and in your view you can always check whether its edit or add

```
   if ($this->request->params['action'] == 'admin_edit') {
    //do something
}
if ($this->request->params['action'] == 'admin_add') {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in edit.ctp

```
if($this->data[ModelName]['id']) {
   $this->Form->input('id');
}

// create rest of the fields
```

in Controller::add()

```
$this->autoRender=false; // at the start of function

$this->render('edit.ctp'); // at the point where you actually want to render
```

no need to create add.ctp